# Referencing elements in RadListView itemtemplate

Tags: nativescript, radlistview

I'm using RadListView and intercepting onItemLoading event.

Within that event, can I reference individual view elements inside the itemTemplate.

I see args.view._subViews - but I was wondering whether i could find element by name or something else. I assume id would not work because each item would have the same id.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct getting by Id would only return the first one.  However, if you have the reference to the ListView child group; using id will work to get the element out of a group.

Now if you use my `NativeScript-Dom` plugin then it is very simple; you can do:
`var elements = RadListView.getElementsByClassName('someClass');` or `RadListView.getElementsByTagName('Label');`   or the newer functionality `

`RadListView.runAgainstTagNames('Label', function(element) {
 /* do something with this element */
});`

And work with an array of elements that match your criteria.

Please also note that in a ListView that not all elements are preset; ListViews only have as many elements are needed to fill the ListView + 1 typically; so even if you have 2,000 items in the list view; you might only have 10 actual child ListView groups of elements. So when you did a GetElementsByTagNames('Label') you would only get 10 of them...

Comment: Since I'm doing this in the onItemLoading() event and have access to the root view object - I would want to set the root when doing the search like runAgainst TagNames() etc. Is that possible. or would that be rootView.runAgainst..(). That would work. Where can I get this plug-in?

Comment: Yes, the plugin was designed to run off of whatever root view you want to use.  That was the reason I used "RadListView" as the root in this case to show you can limit it to a view's children.  You can also do a `runAgainstTagNames('Label');` without a root and it will do the entire page.  ;-)

Now as to where to get it; `tns plugin add nativescript-dom` will add it to your app; the repo/docs is located at https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-dom and you can always find any NS plugins on http://plugins.nativescript.rocks